# Can't animate flutter widget after making it visible for a second time using AnimationController

Tags: flutter, animationcontroller

I'm animating a widget using AnimationController (The widget is the red wave shown in the image attached).  The widget starts with `visibility = false` and turns true for periods of 10 seconds after the user hits the red button to speak.  The problem I'm facing is that when hitting the red button for a second time I get the error:

> AnimationController.stop() called after AnimationController.dispose().

And the widget never shows again.  Since I'm not disposing the widget just hiding it, I can't understand what is going on.  I have tried so far:

- Create the `_controller` outside/inside widget build.
- Check if the widget is mounted before calling it
- Change the `AnimationController` state to false anytime the widget is hidden.

None has worked.  Any idea what is wrong in my code:
[image: spinkitWaveWidget]

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  var _controller;   
  var spinkitWave;
  stt.SpeechToText speech = stt.SpeechToText();
   
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync:this, duration: Duration(seconds:1), lowerBound:0, upperBound:0.1)
     ..addStatusListener((status) {
            if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
             if (mounted) {
              _controller.reverse();
             }
  }});         

  @override
  dispose() {
    _controller.dispose(); // you need this
       super.dispose();
  } 

  void startListening() {
   _controller = AnimationController(vsync:this, duration: Duration(seconds:1), lowerBound:0, upperBound:0.1);
    speech.listen(onResult: resultListener,
    onSoundLevelChange: soundLevelListener,
    cancelOnError: true,);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      spinkitWave = SpinKitWave(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          type: SpinKitWaveType.center,
        controller: _controller,
        );    
       
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        ),
        home: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                           title: Text("Leurebeng"),
                  ),
                  body: Center(
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: 10,
                          child: Stack(
                              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                SizedBox
                                width: 110.0,
                                  height: 110.0,
                                  child: Visibility(
                                    visible: !speech.isListening,
                                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                                      onPressed:
                                        _available ? startListening : initSpeechState,
                                      tooltip: 'Increment',
                                      child: Icon(Icons.mic),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Visibility(
                                  visible: speech.isListening, //Turns true or false after red button pressed
                                  child: 
                                  spinkitWave
                                ),
                              ]),
                        ),                 
                    ),
                  ),
          );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you declare `_controller` 2 times. First time in `initState(){}` where it starts playing and second time in `startListening(){}` where it is overridden and never played again. If you want to start/stop the animation, you can do it like this :

```
_controller.isAnimating
    ? _controller.stop()
    : _controller.forward();
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things you need to clear it before applying actual solution here are

1. Neven use var keyword to initialize a disposable type
2. Don't reinitialize your variable after declaration like how you have done it in initState and StartListening

To solve your problem you can wrap your dispose method as

```
if(_animationController){
  _animationController.dispose()
}
```

And second, try using

```
if(mounted){
  // your code
}
```

on the callback you have created which will prevent for the error you are facing

Answer (score 0):

`dispose()` is being called on the `_controller` when the animation completes.

As noted by other commenters, there are a few things that need to be addressed with your code, but I will focus on the solutions to your `AnimationController` problems.

There are a few ways that you could prevent this error. The simplest is to call `_controller.repeat(reverse: true);` after initializing your controller in `initState`. This will cause it to run back and forth indefinitely. Then you can simply toggle `_isListening` to show/hide the animation.

You could also remove the initialization in `initState` and re-initialize upon every call to `startListening()`. If you do this, you will need to be sure to dispose of the controller before initializing a new one. This can be done by calling `_controller.stop()`. According to your needs, this can be a callback after a set `Duration` via `Future.delayed()`, upon release of a button, or any number of other methods.